Move google drive backuped folders to new computer
I have google drive synced folders that appear under the "Computers" section on google drive. Now I would like to move this data to a new laptop but without deleting it on the old one!
The last part is the important aspect. I can move on google drive itself the synced data to the new computer after creating the according folder structure. However doing that move deletes the data on the old computer.
So how can I do that move without deleting the files on the old laptop?

If you're logged into the same Google account with the desktop app on both computers, you should have all your files on both computers.

I'm not talking about the standard google drive folder but backup & Sync of specific folder which are displayed in google drive under computers tab.
